# Adding different text to each pop up box

Tags: javascript, html

I'm relatively new to this all and am wanting to integrate this code pen code into my personal site. I've gotten it all setup except that I want the text to be different for each image pop up and it is set up to be the same on each one. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

https://codepen.io/ste-vg/pen/NALWrj

```
<div class="container" ng-class="{'no-scroll': selected.length}" ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="grid-item" ng-repeat="item in boxes">
                <box class="box" item="item" on-select="selectBox" ng-class="{'selected': selected[0].item.name == item.name}"></box>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fullscreen-background top-up" ng-show="selected.length" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(' + selected[0].item.image + ')'}"></div>
    <div class="scroller" ng-show="selected.length">
        <a class="close-button" ng-click="clearSelection()">
            <i class="material-icons">close</i>
        </a>
        <h1>{{selected[0].item.name}}</h1>
        <div big-box ng-repeat="item in selected" class="box on-top" position="item.position" selected="item.item">
            <img ng-src="{{item.item.image}}" alt="" />
            <div class="content">
                <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime laborum perferendis, ullam minus. Illo ad aliquid ab magni, enim nesciunt at consequuntur dolores explicabo nisi. Dolor, reiciendis suscipit alias nemo.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

add your data to every image item.
lie this:

```js
$scope.boxes = [{
        name: 'Friends',
        image: 'https://source.unsplash.com/uAgLGG1WBd4/900x900',
        title:"new title", // title for every image
        desc:"this is desc from hank" // desc for every image
    }
    ///... other items
```

and then in the template:

```html
        <div class="content">
                <h2>{{item.item.title? item.item.title : "DEFAULT TITLE"}}</h2>
<p>{{item.item.desc? item.item.desc: "DEFAULT DESC"</p>
<!-- other code -->
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! That worked! Out of curiosity would there be any way of doing it in which each individual content was in the HTML code instead of the Javascript file? Ideally I would like to include links, images, etc. within each text description.

Comment: it's data, you should include them into your javascript code, even if your image length is static, you should not put the text in the HTML. or you can use some simple data format like json to store your image data.

Answer (score 0):

I think I get it.

**Add the text field for your every photo. Your Javascript code (into $scope.boxes) should change like the below**

```
$scope.boxes = [
        {
            name: "Friends",
            image: "https://source.unsplash.com/uAgLGG1WBd4/900x900",
            text: "this is first photo"
        },
        {
            name: "Free",
            image: "https://source.unsplash.com/Cp-LUHPRpWM/900x900",
            text: "this is second photo"
        },
        {
            name: "Explore",
            image: "https://source.unsplash.com/7BjmDICVloE/900x900",
            text: "this is third photo"
        },
        {
            name: "Vast",
            image: "https://source.unsplash.com/WLUHO9A_xik/900x900",
            text: "this is fourth photo"
        },
        {
            name: "Playful",
            image: "https://source.unsplash.com/b2-fBVrfx0o/900x900",
            text: "this is fifth photo"
        },
        {
            name: "Grand",
            image: "https://source.unsplash.com/Ixp4YhCKZkI/900x900",
            text: "this is sixth photo"
        },
        {
            name: "Mist",
            image: "https://source.unsplash.com/8BmNurlVR6M/900x900",
            text: "this is seventh photo"
        },
        {
            name: "Sea",
            image: "https://source.unsplash.com/6YqpFWWQsno/900x900",
            text: "this is eighth photo"
        },
        {
            name: "Reach",
            image: "https://source.unsplash.com/zFnk_bTLApo/900x900",
            text: "this is nineth photo"
        },
        {
            name: "Awe",
            image: "https://source.unsplash.com/j4PaE7E2_Ws/900x900",
            text: "this is tenth photo"
        },
        {
            name: "Surf",
            image: "https://source.unsplash.com/uohGiEVhWiQ/900x900",
            text: "this is eleventh photo"
        },
        {
            name: "Thrill",
            image: "https://source.unsplash.com/ssrbaKvxaos/900x900",
            text: "this is twelfth photo"
        }
    ];
```

**Your HTML code (into div class="content") should change like the below**

```
     <div class="content">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>      
        <p>{{selected[0].item.text}}</p>   //this is important                                                                                                   
     </div>
```

[here is your answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wo9g.png)

Comment: I apologies, I think Hank X wrote the same answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Out of curiosity would there be any way of doing it in which each individual content was in the HTML code instead of the Javascript file? Ideally I would like to include links, images, etc. within each text description.